# Is it OK to edit a question by only adding a tag + very small formatting change?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I answered [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258896/use-send-headers-only-on-a-single-category) and thought it'd be better if I add [`headers`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headers) tag, as it's clearly about `HTTP` headers.

While editing, I also made the following minor changes:

```
http --> `HTTP`
- because HTTP is not a generic word

category X --> category `x`
- to small letter (+ backtick) because in the question, he added the CODE with x, not X
```

I know this is very minor change and I could've only added the `headers` tag. However, my understanding was: since I'm editing it anyway, it's probably better if I improve the formatting as well.

My edit [suggestion was rejected](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/129060). I'm not complaining, I'm simply trying to understand why (so that I may avoid the same mistake in the future).

So my question is:

1. Is it OK if I only add (or remove) tags for my edit suggestion?
2. Am I wrong in those minor changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it OK if I only add (or remove) tags for my edit suggestion?

Yes.

We all try to get tags "clean" from time to time. The more people jump in and "adopt" a tag, the better.

> Am I wrong in those minor changes?

A "minor" edit was defined as *"less than 6 characters"*. Yours was 7 :)

While it was technically correct, and I tend to agree with such edits, yes, *HTTP* should not be written in lower case letters, the edit itself could have improved all the things in need of an edit.

> *Any ideas?*

could have been removed as it does not add any value. It's a question per se, so no need to ask.

> Now, I want to only inject the headers on pages in category `x`.

could get clarifications with a comment up front that asks why the *pages* have categories on this specific site. This might have an impact on the answer.

> I've wrapped the function in `if ( in_category('x') ) {}` but that didn't work.

obviously the code is out of the scope of this "conditional". This means that there might be clarification needed around *when* and *where* the code in the question is executed.

The same goes for the code that was meant to be an edit, but came out as comment.

> I've also tried with wp_headers, and that fails too: `function add_header_xua($headers) { // var_dump($headers); #=> if you want to see the current headers... if ( in_category('x') ) { $headers['X-UA-Compatible'] = 'IE=edge,chrome=1'; } return $headers; } add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_header_xua');` *– Jim Duggan 14 hours ago*

…which was 1 hour *before* the edit.

As you can see, there were some things which really needed an edit and that's the reason I rejected the edit.

Summed up: The community can be glad about everyone who jumps in and wants to edit. Still we need more *full* edits to help questions become better and receive upvotes, than we need minor edits that put the focus on correcting the inner *Woody Allen* and fix *http* vs. the correct *HTTP* version ;)

Hope that helps! If you have further questions, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, but I've one final question, again just for the sake of clarity: if I had made only the tag change and no other change within the content, would you still have rejected it?

Comment: @Fayaz No, I would not. Tag-only edits stand aside from edits and should be treated differently. They can not be "minor" per se, but need a lot of thought themselves. See toschos meta posts about it. About your edit: From zero to (my) hero! Awesome!